# Adding rows to table with jquery, but new rows not submitted to form with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am close on this I know, the jquery to add new rows to the table is working well but when the form is submitted, I'm only getting the input values from the first row only (each row has some inputs). I can't figure out why the rest of the rows, no matter how many exist, are not being picked up in the array.

Js:

```
//add rows
$("#addrow").click(function(){
    i=1;
    var row = '<tr>'
    + '<td><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" style="margin:0 10px 0 -15px"></td>'
    + '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="partid[]" id="pid'+i+'"></td>'
    + '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" step="1" name="partqty[]" id="pqty'+i+'" placeholder="Qty"></td>'
    + '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="0.0001" step="0.0001" name="partlength[]" id="pqty'+i+'" placeholder="Length"></td>'
    + '</tr>';
    i++;
    $("#partstable").append(row);
});
```

The form:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="addrow" value="Add Row">
            <table id="partstable" style="padding:15px;margin:15px;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" style="margin:0 10px 0 -15px"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="partid[]" id="pid[]"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" step="1" name="partqty[]" id="pqty[]" placeholder="Qty"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="0.0001" step="0.0001" name="partlength[]" id="pqty[]" placeholder="Length"></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark delete-row">Delete Row</button>
            
            <input name="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

I expect to see ALL rows, regardless of the qty available in the array below, but I'm only getting the first row no matter what I try...

```
            <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach($_POST['partid'] as $partid){
               $partid = $_POST['partid'];
               print_r($partid);
               $partqty = $_POST['partqty'];
               print_r($partqty);
               $partlength = $_POST['partlength'];
               print_r($partlength);
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `<form>` inside `<tbody>`.

Comment: The `<form>` needs to be wrapped around the entire `<table>`

Comment: @ohgodpleasehelpme are you open to help from anyone, or only the divine?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: I think your issue is also in your PHP code, you are overwriting the variable of your foreach `$partid` inside the loop, that's why you don't see the other values, change the name of the `$partid` to not overwrite the variable.

Comment: @JoseLora I don't really understand this comment but I agree there is something wrong with the array function. I get the array printed too many times, and in the wrong order. I want an array for each row in the table, I'm getting an array with one column per row, for as many rows are exist, x2... it is really confusing. I want to do math per rown.

Comment: @ohgodpleasehelpme I let my answer to your question because I tested your js and HTML side code and everything looks good and your issue is just how you handle the data in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your PHP code, you just need to loop the data in your PHP code like this:

```
<?php

    foreach($_POST['partid'] as $key => $val){
        $partid = $val;
        $partqty = $_POST['partqty'][$key];
        $partlength = $_POST['partlength'][$key];


        echo $partid." ".$partqty." ".$partlength."</br>";
    }

?>
```

You just need to loop the `partid` array and with the key of that array with the `foreach` then select the key of each variable.

Also as @Barmar mentioned fix the `form` tag position like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="addrow" value="Add Row">
    <table id="partstable" style="padding:15px;margin:15px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Length</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>            
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record[]" style="margin:0 10px 0 -15px"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="partid[]" id="pid[]"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" step="1" name="partqty[]" id="pqty[]" placeholder="Qty"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="0.0001" step="0.0001" name="partlength[]" id="pqty[]" placeholder="Length"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark delete-row">Delete Row</button>
    <input name="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, the php is corrected now as well, everything is working as I need it to!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  //add rows
  $("#addrow").click(function() {
    var i = $("#partstable tbody tr").length + 1;
    var row = $("<tr>");
    $("<td>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "record[]"
    }).appendTo($("td:last", row));
    $("<td>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      name: "partid[]",
      id: "pid" + i,
      class: "form-control"
    }).appendTo($("td:last", row));
    $("<td>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      min: 1,
      step: 1,
      name: "partqty[]",
      id: "pqty" + i,
      placeholder: "Qty",
      class: "form-control"
    }).appendTo($("td:last", row));
    $("<td>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      min: 0.0001,
      step: 0.0001,
      name: "partlength[]",
      id: "plength" + i,
      placeholder: "Length",
      class: "form-control"
    }).appendTo($("td:last", row));
    $("#partstable").append(row);
  });

  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
  });
})
```

```css
#partstable tbody tr td>input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 0 10px 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="addrow" value="Add Row">
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <table id="partstable" style="padding:15px;margin:15px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Length</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="record[]"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="partid[]" id="pid1"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" step="1" name="partqty[]" id="pqty1" placeholder="Qty"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" min="0.0001" step="0.0001" name="partlength[]" id="plength1" placeholder="Length"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark delete-row">Delete Row</button>
  <input name="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

There is more code, yet it builds all the parts properly with unique IDs.